# Android YouTubePlayer API won't autoplay videos when ads are embedded.

Tags: android, ads, autoplay, android-youtube-api

So, this is an extremely bad bug for my app.

I have an app that basically relies on videos to autoplay, but the YouTube API wont let you autoplay if they randomly choose to inject an ad first in the video.

I have tried lots of workarounds and eventually I found a half solution, that sort of works. If I detect no sound playing after some interval, I keep trying other videos... which then at some point wont have ads.

Does anyone know of a way to autoplay videos through the YouTube API when ads appear first?

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. The player initializes, briefly starts loading and then stops as if the videos is over. After some time I noticed "Ad" flashes in the bottom left corner briefly. So I made sure to disable ads on my videos, but it doesn't seem to have taken effect, at least not yet. Did you ever find a solution?